# Can a rigid CY threefold have infinitely many automorphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, automorphism-groups, calabi-yau

Let $X$ be a rigid Calabi-Yau threefold. Does $X$ have only finitely many automorphisms?

N.B. A smooth projective threefold $X$ over $\mathbb C$ is a rigid Calabi-Yau variety if $h^i(X,\mathcal O_X) =0$ for all $i>0$, $K_X$ is numerically trivial and $\mathrm{H}^1(X,T_X) =0$ (or equivalently $h^{2,1}(X) = 0$).

Comment: Your definition is wrong.  For a Calabi-Yau variety of dimension $n$, $h^n(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ should be nonzero.

Comment: I assume you mean CY threefolds. Why do you think they would only have a finite automorphism group?

Comment: @JasonStarr Sorry about that. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @LevBorisov My apologies to you as well. I indeed meant threefolds. My problem is that I don't know what to expect to be honest. All I know is that the set of automorphisms fixing an ample line bundle is finite. But I guess this leaves open the possibility of automorphisms not fixing an ample line bundle, and I simply do not know how to construct a rigid CY threefold with such automorphisms.

Comment: You may want to ask Noriko Yui if anybody looked at infinite order automorphisms of rigid CY threefolds. She probably knows as many of these rigid CYs as anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes (to the question in the title; no to the question in the first line).  You can find an example in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.1590) by Oguiso and Truong.  The variety ``$X$'' should do what you want.

Briefly, let $\omega = (1+\sqrt{3}i)/2$ and let $E$ be the elliptic curve $\mathbb C / (\mathbb Z + \omega \mathbb Z)$.  Then $E$ has an automorphism $\tau$ of order $3$ given by multiplication by $\omega$.  Let $X$ be the crepant resolution of $(E \times E \times E)/\tau$ with the diagonal action.  Then $X$ is a Calabi-Yau threefold, with many automorphisms, induced by the action of $\textrm{SL}_3(\mathbb Z[\omega])$ on $E \times E \times E$.  This $X$ is apparently rigid; there are refs in the paper.